# Remove &nbsp; from class=""

Tags: javascript

Hello i tried to remove `&nbsp;` from `<span class="Odbanowany&nbsp;">`.

I add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('.purple_shadow');
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
  }
</script>
```

but it didn't work, on jsfiddle works but on mybb still nothing.
Anyone can help me ?

Comment: what does `Odbanowany` and `.purple_shadow'` have in common?

Comment: Shouldn't you be selecting by class `.Odbanowany`?

Comment: sorry i forgot show where is nbsp;

Comment: Odbanowany is a class .Odbanowany , but class in css is not working because something is still ading nbsp in class

Comment: if you are trying to alter the value of the `class` attribute, you need to update the `className`, not the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: You should probably correct whatever is putting a `&nbsp;` in the classname in the first place, rather than patching it over after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit the class with inner HTML replace. You need to select the bad class and replace it.

```
$('.Odbanowany&nbsp;').AddClass('Odbanowany').RemoveClass('Odbanowany&nbsp;');
```

I would find the cause of the added   and fix this issue there though.